# Jasmine test thinks data isn't being parsed correctly

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, jasmine

I have a method I'm testing in Jasmine, and part of it's functionality is that it parses a JSON object that I feed to it. If I log the "data" object in the browser console, it looks like the JSON was parsed just fine, but when I run the test, I get **SyntaxError: Unexpected token u.**

This is the test (I'm returning and expecting an arbitrary number while I troubleshoot):

```
describe('The Save Show Form', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {

    saveShow = {
      saveShowToDashboard: function(info, csrf) {
        const showInfo = info;
        const parsedShowInfo = JSON.parse(showInfo);
        const _csrf = csrf;
        const data = {
          tourInfo: parsedShowInfo,
          token: _csrf
        };
        console.log(data);
        return 2;
      }
    };

    spyOn(saveShow, 'saveShowToDashboard').and.callThrough();

    saveShow.saveShowToDashboard(testShowInfo, test_csrf);

  });

  it('Should return a value of 2 for this test.', function() {
    expect(saveShow.saveShowToDashboard()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

...and this is the dummy data I'm passing to it:

```
const testShowInfo = '{"id": "11655593", "artist": "Odesza", "date": "Thursday, March 24, 2016 at 10:00PM", "venue": "Pacific Coliseum", "location": "Vancouver, Canada", "tickets": "available"}';

const test_csrf = 'KGSa3p5f-eJDLDjksk6FQmRqx2aouBU9zY-w';
```

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: this code is not enough.can you upload partial functionality on github?

Comment: Really strange. Just directly calling `JSON.parse(testShowInfo)` works okay. Have you tried adding a log to `saveShowToDashboard()`, in order to check if `info` wasn't somehow corrupted?

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Yeah and everything is fine. The function in this test is a replica of one I'm using in an application. The functionality works perfectly in the app.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN The only other code involved is the html linking test source and test spec files, which I've verified is not the issue.

Comment: At least share the definition of info

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN testShowInfo is being passed in for info. I incorrectly assumed that I only needed to pass arguments to the function call iniside the beforeEach function, when I actually needed to pass them to it in the assertion as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue here was that I wasn't passing arguments to the function call inside the assertion. I incorrectly assumed that I only needed to do so inside the beforeEach function.

I was getting **SyntaxError: Unexpected token u** because JSON.parse() was being passed a value of undefined.

The assertion should read as follows:

```
it('Should return a value of 2 for this test.', function() {
    expect(saveShow.saveShowToDashboard(testShowInfo, test_csrf)).toEqual(2);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If `saveShow` is the our controller then I expect you injected it properly as you are using it's
`saveShowToDashboard` method.

Now instead of defining like this `const testShowInfo` and `const test_csrf`

you should define it like this one in your controller

```
$scope.testShowInfo = '..';
$scope.test_csrf ='..';
```

As defining it with `const or var` make it visible only withing controller and can
not be injectable in jasmine script.

JS :

```
var controller,saveShow;
beforeEach( inject( function(_$controller_,$rootScope){
    controller= controller_;
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();;
    saveShow = controller("saveShow",{$scope : scope});
}));





 describe('The Save Show Form', function() {

            beforeEach(function() {

                    it("json should be defined", function() {

                        const showInfo = save.Showinfo;
                        const test_csrf = save.test_csrf;

                        const parsedShowInfo = JSON.parse(saveShow.showInfo);

                        saveShow.saveShowToDashboard(testShowInfo, test_csrf);
                    })
                };
            });
```